That is a statement from the West Mercia Police there
On TV, they are talking to a woman whose father killed her mom. When they are talking the police sent a statement about what they had done before the incident. The TV presenter read it and said:
"That is a statement from the West Mercier Police there." ITV - this morning (see:7:25-7:30)
Why is there a "there" at the end of the sentence, when the sentence can mean the same without it, too?

That's the way TV presenters sometimes talk. That's a thing there (that you just heard). They are not grammar teachers. Also, it's West Mercia Police.

I did once visit Champagne Mercier, at Epernay in France, but that's the next country along...

You cannot apply the same level of scrutiny to extemporaneous speech as you do to the written word. Most people begin a sentence without knowing exactly how it will end, so reading back a transcript will often highlight what would be grammatical mistakes in a written piece. It is exceedingly common for news reporters working in a live environment to mix up tenses because they are commentating on things that are happening as they speak. But, having said that, I don't see anything unusual about this piece.
The presenter said "that is a statement..." but she said that after she had finished reading it. She perhaps could have said "that was a statement....", except she was still holding the piece of paper at the time, so she likely said "is" because she was still looking at it. She added "there" as she was putting the paper down, and 'there' is an adverb of position. We sometimes say "there" to verbally mark or emphasize the action of putting an object in a specific location. In fact, "there" is sometimes the only word spoken as we put something in its place. So, one way to view the addition is that the presenter was speaking about the piece of paper as 'the statement, but also it isn't unusual to say "there" about something non-physical to denote that something has finished, or to draw attention to something that has just happened.

It isn't the prosody of "There!" at the end of a statement or action which has the meaning "That's over and done with!" or "Finished!".
The prosody of there in that utterance indicates that it has roughly this meaning in context :

That is a statement from the West Mercia Police [you just heard/I just read out].

It is in support of "That", which points something out, and can refer back to something that has just been said.  It is just a little bit of extra help in keeping the listener oriented.
In some dialects you might hear :

What's this thing?
--That there is a bullrake for gathering hay.


That was quite a goal there! That was a good joke you told there!
